# Empty HTML Emails In Outlook.com When Using MSO Conditional <!--[if !mso]>

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

So I am using @font-face in my emails and Outlook 2007, 2011 and 2013 were giving me trouble. So I wrapped the @font-face CSS in conditional < !--[if !mso] > tags and this works great for CSS specific styles in outlook (desktop client) but this Completely breaks my emails in outlook.com. They come through blank as in no content! A completely white nothingness!

I've tried various forms of the outlook conditional tags such as < !--[if !mso] >

Below is my current code:

```
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
       <style type="text/css">
          @import url(http://image.commonsensemedia-email.org/lib/fea013707564077e77/m/5/csm-fonts.css);
       </style>
    <![endif]-->
```

Also below is a litmus test so you can see the results:

https://litmus.com/pub/a49f7b4/screenshots

Any reason why these emails are completely empty in outlook.com?

------UPDATE:2/18/2014 MY SOLUTION ------

This seemed to work perfectly across all platforms. Once I removed all HTML from comment tags everything worked great.

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url(http://image.commonsensemedia-email.org/lib/fea013707564077e77/m/5/csm-fonts.css);
    </style>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: This is [the best way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467381/can-outlook-2010-use-a-web-font-in-an-html-email/21485767#21485767) I've forund to do webfonts in html email

Comment: I was handing off the HTML for a client to edit so I had to make it simple. I posted the solution that worked well for me. Thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recently, I ran into an issue with blank emails for outlook.com (@hotmail and @live) email accounts. The issue we experienced had to do with CSS comments in our inline stylesheets. Basically, what fixed the blank email experience for me was changing CSS comments to server-side comments (or deleting them entirely). If I had CSS comments like `/* comment */` in our CSS, outlook.com would render blank emails.

**[View possible solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10613528/why-hotmail-dont-show-the-body-of-this-html-email/21535955#21535955)**

In addition, I personally don't think its good practice to use external stylesheets in HTML emails (or email in general). It is best to add your CSS via `<style></style>` tags in the `<head>` of your template/email, or to go further and inline that same CSS to each HTML element in the email. Here's some background on why you shouldn't include external stylesheets in email:

- [Can you link to a CSS file from an email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105963/can-you-link-to-a-css-file-from-an-email)
- http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css (manual inline tool)
- http://www.benchmarkemail.com/help-FAQ/answer/Common-HTML-Email-Coding-Mistakes

### Update

As `@digitalmc` pointed out in the comments, it seems the issue is related to having HTML in your client side comments.

Comment: Yeah all my styles are inline or plced in header. I'm using @ import for the @ font-face method only because it's more widely supported then puting @ font-face directly into the email. 

I do have a lot of CSS comments so I will try removing those and seeing what happens. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Maybe you could try an image replacement instead of @font-face? Where inside your conditional outlook tags, you use CSS to hide the normal text and replace with an image. I'm assuming that your @font-face is for titles or other phrases, not loads of content.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good diea except it's actually for a block of copy that the client will be changing week to week. I'm building templates for them and they (a marketer) will update copy. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Turns out you were right (mostly)! Thanks for you help. The issue was in my comments within the CSS. The issue was not the comments themselves, but rather putting code in the comment tags. Once I removed code from comment tags (it was a simple < td > I used to describe something) It was fixed. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.